# Local storage saving multiples of the same items

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, jquery-mobile, local-storage

I'm quite new to using storage settings in HTML/JavaScript. I'm building a hybrid app which is a not taking app on mobile using Phonegap. I want the user to type in a note name, then the note itself, and be able to save both by placing them into a jquery mobile list and putting them back on the home screen. My problem is that I can only save one note at a time. If I try to save another one, it just overwrites the previous one. How would I go about fixing it? Also, when I try refresh the browser the note disappears. Is this normal? 
Please and thank you.

Here is the saving function I used:

```
function storeData() {  
    var i;
    for (i=0; i<999; i++) {
    var fname = document.getElementById('fname').value;
    var wtf = document.getElementById('wtf').value;

    localStorage.setItem('fname', fname);
    localStorage.setItem('wtf', wtf); 



}

    var newEl = "<li><a href='#' id='savedNote'onclick='loadData'></a></li>"

    document.getElementById("savedNote").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("fname");

    //try to create a new list element in main menu for this item being stored in 
    // and add an onclick load function for that
```

};

```
function loadData() {
var x;
for (x=0; x<999; x++) {

document.getElementById("fname").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('fname', fnamei);
document.getElementById("wtf").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('wtf', wtfi);


}
```

};

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you're using a loop for your functions. The storeData function looks 999 times for the value of #fname and #wtf, and save this 999x times in `localStorage.fname` and `localStorage.wtf`
This makes absolut no sense. Same Problem with your loadData function.

A nice way to save more then one string to the localStorage, is to create a javascript object, stringify it and then save it to the localStorage.

You only need to load the data from the localStorage, if you (re)load the page. But you need to save it to the localStorage, every time something changed, to be sure that the data in the localStorage is always up to date.

For display and manipulation on the page, you use the javascript object. in my example "myData". If you change something, you update your javascript object and then save it to the localStorage.

a side note. to be sure that the user don't overwrite something with a 
identical name, you should use unique ids. like i did with the timestamp.

```
var postID =  new Date().getTime();
```

Here a little example to show you a possible way. It's hard to code something functionally without your html code.

```js
// Creating a object for all Data
var myData = {};
   
// Fill the Object with data if there is something at the LocalStorage
if (localStorage.myData){
 loadDataFromLocalStorage();
}

function createNewPost(){
  
  // Create a ID for the Post
  var postID =  new Date().getTime();
    
  // Create a Object inside the main object, for the new Post
  myData[postID] = {};
  // Fill the Object with the data
  myData[postID].fname = document.getElementById('fname').value;
  myData[postID].wtf =  document.getElementById('wtf').value;
    
  // Save it to the LocalStorage
  saveDataToLocalStorage();
    
  // Display the Listitem. with the right postID

}

function loadPost (postID){
 var singlePost = myData[postID];
    
 // Display it 
}
   
   
// A Helper Function that turns the myData Object into a String and save it to the Localstorage
function saveDataToLocalStorage(){
 localStorage.myData = JSON.stringify(myData);
}
   
// A Helper Function that turns the string from the LocalStorage into a javascript object 
function loadDataFromLocalStorage(){
 myData = JSON.parse(localStorage.myData);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
// Creating a object for all Data
var myData = {};
   
// Fill the Object with data if there is something at the LocalStorage
if (localStorage.myData){
 loadDataFromLocalStorage();
}

function createNewPost(){
  
  // Create a ID for the Post
  var postID =  new Date().getTime();
    
  // Create a Object inside the main object, for the new Post
  myData[postID] = {};
  // Fill the Object with the data
  myData[postID].fname = document.getElementById('fname').value;
  myData[postID].wtf =  document.getElementById('wtf').value;
    
  // Save it to the LocalStorage
  saveDataToLocalStorage();
    
  // Display the Listitem. with the right postID

}

function loadPost (postID){
 var singlePost = myData[postID];
    
 // Display it 
}
   
   
// A Helper Function that turns the myData Object into a String and save it to the Localstorage
function saveDataToLocalStorage(){
 localStorage.myData = JSON.stringify(myData);
}
   
// A Helper Function that turns the string from the LocalStorage into a javascript object 
function loadDataFromLocalStorage(){
 myData = JSON.parse(localStorage.myData);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Store an array.

```
var arrayX = [];

arrayX.push(valueY);

localStorage.setItem('localSaveArray', arrayX);
```